# Pagination using wrapper Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, pagination

I have this piece of code that works pretty fine, for "next" and "previous" buttons - however, despite my efforts, I have not been able to write effective code for "first" and "last" button. Please suggest.

The custom iterable class is:

```
public class  NewClass implements Iterator<List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass>>{ 

   //***Initilaizations
   public List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass> initialList{get;set;}
   public List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass> nextList{get;set;}
   public Integer i {get;set;} 
   public Integer setPageSize {get;set;} 


   //***Constructor
   public NewClass(List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass> docList){
       initialList = new List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass>(); 
       nextList = new List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass>();     
       initialList = docList;
       setPageSize = 10;
       i = 0; 
   }   



   //***Method to identify if there are next set of results
   public boolean hasNext(){ 
       if(i >= initialList.size()) {
           return false; 
       } else {
           return true; 
       }
   } 



   //***Method to identify if there are previous set of results
   public boolean hasPrevious(){ 
       if(i <= setPageSize) {
           return false; 
       } else {
           return true; 
       }
   }   


   //***Method to fetch next set of results
   public List<SomeClass.ProductWrapper> next(){       
       nextList = new List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass>(); 
       Integer startNumber;
       Integer size = initialList.size();
       if(hasNext()){  
           if(size <= (i + setPageSize)){
               startNumber = i;
               i = size;
           }
       else{
               i = (i + setPageSize);
               startNumber = (i - setPageSize);
           }

       for(integer start = startNumber; start < i; start++){
               nextList.add(initialList[start]);
          }
       } 
       return nextList;
   } 



   //***Method to fetch previous set of results
   public List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass> previous(){      
       nextList = new List<Someclass.InnerWrapperClass>(); 
       integer size = initialList.size(); 
       if(i == size){
         if(Math.mod(size, setPageSize) > 0){    
               i = size - Math.mod(size, setPageSize);
         }
         else{
               i = (size - setPageSize);
             } 
       }
       else{
           i = (i - setPageSize);
           }

       for(Integer start = (i - setPageSize); start < i; ++start){
           nextList.add(initialList[start]);
       } 
       return nextList;
   }   
}
```

This custom iterable class is called by an another class where we pass the complete wrapper list in the "initialList" variable stated above.

```
for(Product__c s : prods){
          initialproductsList.add(new InnerWrapperClass(s,false));
      }

      obj = new NewClass(initialproductsList);
      obj.setPageSize  = PAGE_SIZE;
      next();
```

Comment: you might want to post what you've tried for `first()` and `last()`

Answer (score 0):

Your custom logic structures are a bit hard to follow, but it seems like `first()` and `last()` methods would function identically to your `next()` method, only you'd need to set the `startNumber` to `0` or `initialList.size()-setPageSize-1`, respectively